# Finding the string "/.env" in all files on a webserver

Tags: linux, apache

We have a huge amount of requests being made by the webserver to domain.com/.env
Its making our webhost angry as its increasing CPU usage substantially.

We are not managing environment variables like this so I don't know why its happening. And we cant work out what's triggering it (checked cron jobs etc). Also checked for any malicious scripts etc.
We want to find what is configured to query /.env so logged in via SSH and tried searching using:

```
grep -inr "/.env"
```

But this is painfully slow. ​Is there an easier way to search the entire directory for anything containing that string

Comment: "the entire directory" remains unidentified in your question.

Comment: I was running it inside the directory I wanted to search.

Comment: I think I could have better phrased my question by asking how to find anything on my webserver which is using/requesting environment variables.

Comment: Try this from the top directory: `find . -type f -exec grep "\.env" {} \; -print`.  But it will take time to go through each file, no way around that.